Nestjs can't resolve dependencies in RootTestModule context when I use Jest Test
I need to run my tests in Jest but the service and controller dependencies are not being recognized in my Nestjs testing files.
I'm really new to testing and Nestjs so I would appreciate any patience one can spare!
I've gone through all the Stack Overflow posts on this error and I've tried their approaches to the hilt but to no avail.
When I run the tests for the whole Nestjs backend which I'm testing for my job I get this error:
  Potential solutions:
    - Is RootTestModule a valid NestJS module?
    - If JurisdictionRepository is a provider, is it part of the current RootTestModule?
    - If JurisdictionRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RootTestModule?
      @Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing JurisdictionRepository */ ]
      })

      25 |
      26 |   beforeEach(async () => {
    > 27 |     const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
         |                                   ^
      28 |       providers: [
      29 |         JurisdictionService,
      30 |         {

And here is one of the other variations that I tried
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
        providers: [JurisdictionService],
        controllers: [JurisdictionController]
  
    }).compile();

Here is the complete code example:
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { JurisdictionService } from './jurisdiction.service';
import { JurisdictionController } from './jurisdiction.controller';
// import { Jurisdiction } from './jurisdiction.entity';
import { JurisdictionRepository } from './jurisdictions.repository';
import { Jurisdiction } from './../../database/entities/jurisdiction.entity';

class MockJurisdictionRepository {
  dataSource = {};
  updateAdder = jest.fn();
  findAllAndCount = jest.fn();
  deleteAdder = jest.fn();
  primeNgTableFindAll = jest.fn();
  create = jest.fn();
  save = jest.fn();
  findOne = jest.fn();
  // ...other methods
}

describe('JurisdictionService', () => {
  let service: JurisdictionService;
  let controller: JurisdictionController;
  let repository: MockJurisdictionRepository;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        JurisdictionService,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(Jurisdiction),
          useClass: MockJurisdictionRepository,
        },
      ],
      controllers: [JurisdictionController],
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get<JurisdictionController>(JurisdictionController);
    service = module.get<JurisdictionService>(JurisdictionService);
    repository = module.get<MockJurisdictionRepository>(getRepositoryToken(Jurisdiction));
  });

  
  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
    expect(repository).toBeDefined();
  });
});

Here is the module for the component:
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
// import { Jurisdiction } from 'src/database/entities/jurisdiction.entity';
import { Jurisdiction } from './../../database/entities/jurisdiction.entity';
import { JurisdictionController } from './jurisdiction.controller';
import { JurisdictionService } from './jurisdiction.service';
import { JurisdictionRepository } from './jurisdictions.repository';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Jurisdiction])],
controllers: [JurisdictionController],
  providers: [JurisdictionService, JurisdictionRepository],
})
export class JurisdictionModule {}

And here is the App/Root Module:
import { MailerModule } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AuthModule } from './modules/auth/auth.module';
import { join } from 'path';
import { HandlebarsAdapter } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer/dist/adapters/handlebars.adapter';
import { UserModule } from './modules/user/user.module';
import { DocumentsModule } from './modules/documents/documents.module';
import { CustomersModule } from './modules/customers/customers.module';
import { ProposalsModule } from './modules/proposals/proposals.module';
import { FinanceModule } from './modules/finance/finance.module';
import { DesignsModule } from './modules/designs/designs.module';
import { SearchModule } from './modules/search/search.module';
import { AddersModule } from './modules/adders/adders.module';
import { PartnersModule } from './modules/partners/partners.module';
import { JurisdictionModule } from './modules/jurisdiction/jurisdiction.module';
import { BatteriesModule } from './modules/batteries/batteries.module';
import { ModulesEquipmentModule } from './modules/modules-equipment/modules-equipment.module';
import { InvertersModule } from './modules/inverters/inverters.module';
import { FilesModule } from './modules/files/files.module';
import { DrawingsModule } from './modules/drawings/drawings.module';
import { IssueReportModule } from './modules/issue-report/issue-report.module';
import { TemplatesModule } from './modules/templates/templates.module';
import { PlacedPanelModule } from './modules/drawings/placed-panel/placed-panel.module';


@Module({
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
        transport: {
          host: config.get('EMAIL_HOST'),
          secure: false,
          port: config.get('EMAIL_PORT'),
          auth: {
            user: config.get('EMAIL_USER'),
            pass: config.get('EMAIL_PASSWORD'),
          },
        },
        defaults: {
          from: 'No Reply',
        },
        template: {
          dir: join(__dirname, config.get('EMAIL_TEMPLATES_URL')),
          adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
          options: {
            strict: true,
          },
        },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
      username: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
      entities: ['dist/src/database/entities/*.js'],
      synchronize: false,
    }),
    AuthModule,
    UserModule,
    DocumentsModule,
    CustomersModule,
    ProposalsModule,
    FinanceModule,
    DesignsModule,
    SearchModule,
    AddersModule,
    PartnersModule,
    JurisdictionModule,
    BatteriesModule,
    ModulesEquipmentModule,
    InvertersModule,
    FilesModule,
    DrawingsModule,
    IssueReportModule,
    TemplatesModule,
    PlacedPanelModule,
    
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}

I have read through the Nestjs documentation and followed their approach and still got a flood of other errors. I have mocked the repository and the service in two different tests but I still got the same errors or errors saying that I needed to include arguments here:
describe('CatsController', () => {
  let catsController: CatsController;
  let catsService: CatsService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    catsService = new CatsService();
    catsController = new CatsController(catsService);
  });

And I've tried many different configurations of the Service, Controller, and Repository configuration in the before hook but I still got the same error or errors.
When mocking a service or repository sometimes I'd get errors saying that the repository was missing types or methods. I believe I took each approach and configuration to it's perceivable limits solving all the errors until I came to the root one.
